# Signing Flash App for Mac Store Error - signature too large to embed

Tags: macos, flash, store, sign

Trying to sign my app for the Mac App Store. I have a new install of EI Captain and am signing the same as previous versions (last updated my app in January 2016).
I keep getting the error - signature too large to embed (size limitation of on-disk representation).

The development certificate works fine, it's just the production certificate I'm having trouble with.

Anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Feaured post at Apple Developer Forums: WWDR Intermediate Certificate Expiration Update  https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/116171

Comment: Did you find the reason for this error? I'm getting the same errorafter updating to OS X 10.11, but using the same signature and same script for signing as always.

Comment: @user2965639 I was eventually able to package my app. Some of the files I had to sign without time stamping. Apple says Adobe is packaging the AIR runtime with the AIR and AIR_64 in the same folder, which they should not.

Comment: Thanks so much! When using `--timestamp=none` option for `codesign` the error disappeared and my applications are now properly signed again with Developer ID for distribution outside of Mac Store. I still don't get it and do not see why time stamping could cause such an error message, but i'm glad about the workaround!